# How to make a NSSound loop

Tags: swift, cocoa, nssound

I'm attempting to make a simple application on XCode (in Swift) that plays an audio file, then keeps looping infinitely. According to [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nssound/1477311-loops), I need to add `var loops: Bool { get set }` to my code; but I'm not sure how to combine that with my current code in a way that doesn't give an error.

This is what I have so far:

```
let song = NSSound(named: "song.mp3")?.play()
var loops: Bool { get set }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
// create an instance    
let song = NSSound(named: "song.mp3")

// set `loops` property to be true    
song?.loops = true

// start to play   
song?.play()
```

Comment: Thanks; I didn't realize it was that simple.